# Демонстрация экрана средствами браузера

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Ситуация такая: есть собственная площадка для проведения вебинаров, нужно сделать так чтобы ведущий вебинара по нажатию одной кнопки мог транслировать демонстрацию своего экрана всем участниками этого вебинара.

На [площадке](https://webinar.ru/) есть такая возможность, ведущий вебинара по нажатию одной кнопки транслирует свой экран только лишь средствами браузера.

Меня интересует то, как можно достать это изображение(видео), желательно с применением средств браузера.

К примеру, на самом сайте просматривать демонстрацию. С серверной частью разберусь.

Comment: 1. Сайт должен работать по https. 2. https://kongaraju.blogspot.ru/2015/07/share-your-over-webscreen-sharing-with.html

Comment: Можно интегрировать youtube или twitch

Answer (score 1):

JS:

```
const videoElem = document.getElementById("video");
const startElem = document.getElementById("start");
const stopElem = document.getElementById("stop");

// Options for getDisplayMedia()

var displayMediaOptions = {
  video: {
    cursor: "never"
  },
  audio: false
};

// Set event listeners for the start and stop buttons
startElem.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  startCapture();
}, false);

stopElem.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  stopCapture();
}, false);

async function startCapture() {

  try {
    let screen = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
    videoElem.srcObject = screen
    sendInfo(screen);
  } catch(err) {
    console.error("Error: " + err);
  }
}

function stopCapture(evt) {
  let tracks = videoElem.srcObject.getTracks();

  tracks.forEach(track => track.stop());
  videoElem.srcObject = null;
}

function sendInfo(data) {
  // Тут отправляем 'data' на сервер 

  /*
  Как отобразить данные из видео
  videoElem.srcObject = (здесь данные с сервера)
  */
}
```

HTML:

```html
<p><button id="start">Start Capture</button>&nbsp;<button id="stop">Stop Capture</button></p>

<video id="video" autoplay></video>
<br>
```

CSS:

```css
#video {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  width: 98%;
  max-width: 860px;
}
```

Тут не обязателен HTTPS, не нужны внешние ресурсы.